# How to get Direction between 2 places?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my app I want to show the Direction between two Place.

I get the Latitude & Longitude for Both two places.

and  want add that lat,long in this URL,

```
   NSURL *strlist = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f"];
```

But when i give lat,long Like this,

```
 NSURL *strlist = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f & daddr=%f,%f",c_lat,c_long,lat,lat]];
```

//c_lat - Current Latitude  //in Double format
//c_long - Current Longitude  //in Double format
//lat - Particular Place Latitude  //in Double format
//lat - Particular Place Longitude //in Double format

In   NSlog("URL:%@",strlist); I got NULL Value.

How to add that Lat  & Long in NSURL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between `%f` and `&`
Similarly remove the space between `&` and `daddr`

It should be like this

```
 NSURL *strlist = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",c_lat,c_long,lat,lat]];
```

Answer (score 2):

This work when you give call to google direction service, please try this,

```
NSString* url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=true",
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",currentLocation.latitude,currentLocation.longitude],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",annotation.coordinate.latitude,annotation.coordinate.longitude]];
```

thanks,
Mayur